# Can I use my Belkin router as a repeater?

Tags: wireless-networking, router

I've got a brand new, unopened Belkin N600 DB router (yay 50% off sale), and I can't seem to figure out if I can use it as a repeater. As far as I can tell, it doesn't support DD-WRT or Tomato, but I'm wondering if there may be some way to rig it up to repeat Wifi. Also, I really need to know before I open it, because, being a bit tight on money at the moment, I'll probably sell it if I can't use it as a repeater.

Finally, two caveats:

- I can't use the other wireless router for anything other than broadcasting straight from the modem (parents are paranoid about anything technological).
- I can't run ethernet to the second router due to the layout of the house.

Thanks so much for the help everyone--if I'm being vague, tell me!

EDIT: Also, the manual [here](http://www.belkin.com/networking/manual/MAN_F9K1102_8820-00777_RevA03_N600.pdf) is pretty useless on this topic as far as I can tell.

Comment: Tried to read the manual?

Comment: Yep, I've tried looking at the manual [here](http://www.belkin.com/networking/manual/MAN_F9K1102_8820-00777_RevA03_N600.pdf), but it seems more like a getting started guide than an actual manual--there's not much about any specific configuration options.

Comment: @gd1 Most manuals will NOT tell you anything about setting it up as a repeater, from my experience.

Comment: Can you define "repeater"?  if you mean connect the router wirelessly to another router, that's a wireless bridge.  According to this link a repeater is something that functions as an access point. I suppose the access point connects with a wire to the router.  This article says it also functions as a client. That's from my attempt at understanding the beginning anyway. http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Universal_Wireless_Repeater   I'm not much of an expert on this, but there is such a thing as a wireless range extender.. perhaps such a thing might help you with whatever you want to do.

Comment: that manual belkin give is atrocious.. unbelievable..  Look though at page 29 in the manual's page numbering.. It shows a snip of grey menu, that's from the web interface. If there is an option then I suppose it's likely to be there. on the left hand side of the web interface.  I have seen a belkin router that had an "access point" mode or a "wireless router mode" or something like that. The so-called access point mode meant turn off router mode. That device I saw  couldn't be a wireless bridge. Some of their devices can be bridges. The left hand side menu might show something.

Answer (score 3):

Try this aricle: [**How to set up a Wireless Bridge between two Belkin routers**](http://www.belkin.com/us/support-article?articleNum=10759).
Belkin routers had this capability since the software settings changed to bridging.

> ## How to set up a Wireless Bridge between two Belkin routers
>
> Setting up a Wireless Bridge allows you to expand the range of the wireless network broadcasted by your main wireless router.  This article will describe the steps needed to do so.
>
> Before proceeding, make sure of the following:
>
> - Wireless Bridge mode must be supported by your routers.
> - The channel must be identical on both the router and the access point.
>
> ### Setting up wireless bridge
>
> **Step 1:** Connect your computer to the `LAN` or `wired port` of the main router.
>
> [image]
>
> **Step 2:** Launch a web browser like Internet Explorer.
>
> **Step 3:** Enter `192.168.2.1` as the router's default IP address in the Address bar, then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
>
> [image]
>
> **NOTE:** If the default IP address doesn't work, check your router's IP address. For instructions, [click here](http://www.belkin.com/us/support-article?rnId=9516).
>
> **QUICK TIP:** You may also enter `http://router` in the Address bar to access the router's web-based setup page.
>
> You will then be directed to the router's web-based setup page similar to the one below. If you want to change or configure any settings, you will need to log in with your router's administrator password by clicking on `Login` at the top right corner of the page.
>
> [image]
>
> **Step 4:** Enter your router's password then click **Submit**.
>
> [image]
>
> **NOTE:** If you haven't set up a password for your router, leave the field blank then click `Submit`.
>
> **Step 5:** Take note of the `LAN/WLAN MAC` address under the `LAN Settings` section.
>
> [image]
>
> **Step 6:** Click `Wireless Bridging` under `Wireless`.
>
> [image]
>
> **Step 7:** Tick the `Enable Wireless Bridging` checkbox.
>
> [image]
>
> **Step 8:** Tick the `Enable ONLY specific Access Points to connect` checkbox.
>
> [image]
>
> **Step 9:** Enter the `LAN/WLAN MAC` address that you took note of earlier in the `AP1` fields.
>
> [image]
>
> **Step 10:** Click `Apply Changes`.
>
> **Step 11:** Repeat **steps 1–8** on the second Belkin router.
>
> **NOTE:** The Wireless Distribution System (WDS) feature is not completely specified in Institute of Electrical and Electronics Engineers (IEEE) or Wi-Fi™ standards.  Therefore, interoperability between 802.11 products of different vendors is not guaranteed.
>
> You should have successfully set up Wireless Bridge between your **two (2)** Belkin routers now.

Answer (score 1):

From what I see in the manual this router probably won't do what your hopping for. if your looking to extend your wireless network or bridge non wireless devices on to the wireless network and don't plan on using this as the device that gets wired to the internet connection, it won't work.

you need a wireless bridge, or a wireless repeater for that. this is neither.

Comment: "hopping for" nice pun!